# Regarding HackerNews api flutter permission denied

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iEbzL.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDvN2.jpg)

Flutter api permission denied .
When I am Hot Restarting flutter app it shows error which I send in photo upload

Flutter app development.
I don't know what to do and the code also available in photo.
Hacker news permission denied

Comment: Please do NOT share code as photos or screenshot. Code is text and thus should be posted as text. Just include it into your question and format it as a code block. 

Also, please be more clear and detailed when describing your problem. Provide as much information and steps for reproducing your problem.